# Can't find a specific list by it's ID

Tags: list, fuel-sdk

I filtered all list subscribers by specific list ID and it returned the subscribers

```
ET_Client client = new ET_Client(parameters);
        ET_List_Subscriber list = new ET_List_Subscriber();
        list.AuthStub = client;
        list.SearchFilter = new SimpleFilterPart() { Property = "ListID", SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals, Value = new string[] { "*********" } };
        GetReturn results = list.Get();
        foreach (ET_List_Subscriber item in results.Results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--ID: " + item.ID );
        }
        Console.WriteLine(results.Results.Length);
        Console.Read();
```

But when I filter for all my lists by the specific list ID, I get 0 results. The list I am looking for is under my groups if that makes any difference.